# get elements by name from a DOMNodeList

Tags: php, dom

In the following code, I retrieve with DOM a list of nodes from an xml document. Then I would like to select, by their tag name, some of these nodes.

```
$index = new DOMDocument();
$index->load('index.xml');
$xpath = new DOMXpath($index);
$related_notions = $xpath->query("/index/notion[name='" . $name . "']/relations/*"); // the variable $name is dynamically defined previously in the script
foreach ($related_notions->getElementsByTagName("superordinate") as $item) {

// do something

}
```

I get the following error: `Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method DOMNodeList::getElementsByTagName()`

I don't understand why the method `getElementsByTagName()` is not defined for `DOMNodeList`. After all, getting elements by their name seems to me something obvious that one might want to do with a node list. At any rate, my actual question is: How can I do what I want to do? That is, in the absence of the method `getElementsByTagName()`, how do I get elements by tag name from a node list?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Debug your code. What's the value of `$related_notions`?

Comment: [`getElementsByTagName()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.getelementsbytagname.php) is a method of [`DOMDocument()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php), not of [`DOMNodeList`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domnodelist.php) returned by `$xpath->query()`.

Comment: see also the example #1 : https://www.php.net/manual/en/domxpath.query.php#refsect1-domxpath.query-examples

Comment: @RezaSaadati: The output of `print(print_r($related_notions, true))` is `DOMNodeList Object ( [length] => 7 )`. @Syscall: I know that `getElementByTagName()` is not a method of `DOMNodeList`. My question is how I can do on a `DOMNodelist` what that method does in other contexts, namely, select from the list certain nodes by their name, so that I can then run a `foreach` loop on that selected list.

Comment: `DOMNodeList` is the wrong object.  Try it with `$index->getElementsByTagName("superordinate")` instead.

Comment: @RezaSaadati: What you propose would work on the code that I have given originally. However, I simplified the code for this post, and I realize now that I oversimplified it. The situation is that part of the xpath expression that I use is a variable that is defined dynamically. That's why I need to use xpath and your proposal does not work for me (I think). Sorry for the oversimplification! I edited the post so that the code now reflects this situation.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to my problem, namely to test for the `nodeName` with an `if` statement inside the `foreach`:

```
$index = new DOMDocument();
$index->load('index.xml');
$xpath = new DOMXpath($index);
$related_notions = $xpath->query("/index/notion[name='" . $name . "']/relations/*");
foreach ($related_notions as $item) {
    if ($item->nodeName == "superordinate") {
        // do something
    }
}
```